# Build a Web Service API (SOAP) inside MVC app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-mvc-2, soap

Can anyone help me on how to build a web service api (soap) inside an MVC app? WCF is fine :) (initially, WCF is not an option.)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add a WCF service endpoint (.svc file) to your MVC application.

Comment: as you mention WCF in stead of soap api, i'm just curious why svc and not webservice? I hear 'favor .svc over webservice' everywhere, but i'm still experiencing a webservice easier to use. So not to judge your answer, but out of curiusity...

Comment: @Michel: No reason, just threw up one quick way to do it.  I have no opinion on which may be better, particularly in this case as the OP didn't provide much information.

Comment: I can't go with WCF... Thanks.

Comment: @Saxman, Yeah, you failed to mention that one. I think you need go back and edit your question, listing what you can and can't do!

Comment: Framework is not on the client's production server, and they DON'T want to go with WCF, at least for now :) Thanks.

Comment: Um, yeah, didn't WCF get released with the .Net Framework v3, and doesn't ASP.Net MVC (even v1) require .Net v3.5?  Meaning if your client can run an ASP.Net MVC app on their production server, then they can run WCF services.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a webservice to your mvc app, it (mvc) is asp.net after all.

If it's in the root of your app you can just call it (the webservice), if you put it in a subdirectory i think you have to create an ignore route (like the default one `routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");`), but i'm not sure if the ignore route is necessary.